# Debugging, MS Access: MySQL Server has gone away (#2006)

Tags: mysql, ms-access, server

I recently setup a nonlocal host for data with MS Access. The problem is that the server goes away based on the timer from what I know. Our tech support believes that it may have something to do with my firewall or router. I am not sure what to diagnose for solving the problem. 
I had found other pages about this error but some are internal MySQL databases which is not the case so code or other IP writing may not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

if your mysql server does not kick/disconnect users. Access will open up and and maintain a connection until the internet connection gets dropped. if you receive server gone away error message it could be either

1. Connection to the server dropped (check your internet connection: although access will try to reconnect, once the connection dropped while actioning something you get this error message)
2. Server restarted or the object you are accessing (table/view/sp) have been modified.
3. your MySQL max connection number is hit (if some other applications are using your server)

start diagnosing your connection to the server by pinging `ping server_ip -t` and see if your connection drop rate. check your mysql server for max connections and maybe logs for disconnected users. Restarting Access will resolve this problem but this is annoying solution i know.

Comment: I get :"reply from ::1: time<1ms" repetitively. Is that normal? Also where would you find what you mention, max connections and maybe logs?

Comment: if you receive reply then connection is perfect.. max connection and logs you will find on the mysql server settings (.conf file and .log file)